# How to print certain lines from a file that begin and end with a conditional string

Tags: java, string, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have a .txt file like this:

```
[abc]
There is 
a lot of
contents here 
[abc]

[def]
Here are 
many other
contents
[def]

[ghi]
and bunch of 
contents here too
[ghi]
```

I want to print out the contents between the tagged strings, for example: print out all the contents between [abc] and [abc], without printing out any [abc] line. How could I accomplish that?

Comment: If all the tagged lines are start with `[` and no other content lines are start with `[` then filter all lines that are start with `[`. regex should be like this `^[.*$` in multiline pattern

Comment: have you achieved what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Use bufferedreader and file reader for input.
loop through line of input and use the string.equals(string method) for your condition.
not writing code for you

```
if (readline) // for opening tag
    while (readline)
        printline
        if (readline) // for closing tag
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

doable in a simple while with a boolean flag

```
boolean printing=false;
while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
    if(line.startsWith("[abc]"){
        printing=!printing;
    }else if (printing){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```